# What does $B(E \times F,G)=L(E \otimes F,G)$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $E, F$ be vector spaces and $G$ be a normed space. Let $B(E\times F,G)$  the set of all bilinear forms on $E \times F$ and $L(E \otimes F,G)$ be the set of all linear mappings from $E \otimes F$ to $G.$ I need to

> show that $$B(E \times F,G)=L(E \otimes F,G).$$

My question is what is meant by equality here?

---

Let $f \in B(E \times F,G).$ Define $g:E \otimes F \to G$ as $$g(x \otimes y)=f(x,y)$$ and extend linearly.  Then $g \in  L(E \otimes F,G).$

Define $T:B(E \times F,G)\to L(E \otimes F,G)$ as $Tf=g.$ I have shown that $T$ is a isometry.

What else do I need to show?

Comment: You probably want to show that it is surjective as well.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Is that all?

Comment: I think that might do it!

Comment: In fact, what you are trying to show is nothing more than the universal property of the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) :)